# How can I count the number of occurences in a .fasta file using a .txt file?

Tags: bash, while-loop, bioinformatics, fasta

I am really new to coding generally. I'm trying to figure out how to write a bash script that can help me find the occurrences of patterns in a fasta file. The occurrences are in a `.txt` file, and are pretty basic:

```
ATTG
CGCCT
TGGAC
GGCCA
etct.
```

I've been trying to write a bash script that looks like:

```
while read pattern;
do
  grep -c -i $pattern [myfile.fasta] > acountoftheoccurances.txt
done < patternfile.txt
```

I've thought that would return the list of all the patterns, then a count, but all I got was a count of the number of occurrences for the last pattern (I tried them all manually to see what I should expect).

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Each iteration of the loop overwrites the previous result file. You want to append with `>>`, or better, redirect the whole loop like `... done < patternfile.txt > acountoftheoccurances.txt`

Comment: ... But fundamentally, processing the same file again and again for each pattern is very inefficient. You want to learn basic Awk so you can do it all in one pass.

Comment: @Fravadona Thanks, I added a second duplicate which covers that (implicitly).

Comment: If you do that you may also count the pattern in the FASTA header  if it exists. You want to make sure that, you exclude the lines (header) that starts with ">" character.